# Baking mocap animation to constraint re-target armature

Tags: animation

I have an armature with motion capture animation on it and I am applying it to a target armature using several Inverse Kinematics constraints and some Copy rotation constraints, can I then apply that animation from the first armature to the second similar to how you can bake other stuff

[image]

Ultimately i want a easy way of transferring the mocap data from the .bvh file rig to the end program Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'Bake animation' button in the animation tab when your target rig is active and in pose mode.
This should bake every movement to a new animation.